# onclick not triggering all codes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show spinner and overlay before sending an ajax request. But The onclick event directly sending the ajax request without showing the overlay and spinner. Can anyone point me out what i'm doing wrong! here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".refreshBtn").on('click', function() {
        $("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
        $(".spinner").css('display', 'block');

        TableDataContent();
    });

    function TableDataContent() {
        $(".all_tab_content").html('');

        var tableDiv = '<div id="Leaderboard" class="tabcontent"><table class="table-striped"><tbody></tbody></table></div>';

        $(".all_tab_content").append(tableDiv);
        var tableBody = $('#Leaderboard tbody');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SHEET_ID}/values/Leaderboard?key={API_KEY}',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });

        $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
        $(".spinner").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? So we know what CSS the spinner and overlay have.

Comment: Where is you refreshBtn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding the spinner before ajax finishes put hide them from inside the `complete` callback so they can be hidden even when the ajax fails.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SHEET_ID}/values/Leaderboard?key={API_KEY}',
async: false,
success: function(response) {

},
complete: function(xhr, textStatus){
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
    $(".spinner").css('display', 'none');
}
});
```

Comment: do i have to use complete callback event if i use aysnc false? i tried. but not working

Comment: You've not removed `async: false` so the problem will still be the same

Answer (score 1):

Your spinner does not show because AJAX requests are asynchronous. It means that it will be executed while the script continue to be executed too.

To correct that, move instructions which hide the overlay and the spinner in the `success` callback of your AJAX.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. But I think it is better to use callbacks instead of the `async` option.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are hiding `.spinner` and `#overlay` without waiting for ajax to complete. `Ajax`'s `success` callback happening when data is received, this is exactly the moment you want hiding `.spinner` and rest.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SHEET_ID}/values/Leaderboard?key={API_KEY}',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
        $(".spinner").css('display', 'none');
        // rest of your business
    }
});
```

Comment: my async is false.. so that shouldn't be a problem i think.

Comment: You've not removed `async: false` so the problem will still be the same

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed the problem is *because* you're using `async: false`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is entirely due to your use of `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice as it prevents the browser from being updated while the request is in progress. It's for this reason you never see the UI changes.

To fix this, remove `async: false` and instead work with the async callbacks of `$.ajax()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".refreshBtn").on('click', function() {
    TableDataContent();
  });

  function TableDataContent() {
    var $indicators = $("#overlay, .spinner").show(); // show the loading indicator when the request starts...

    var tableDiv = '<div id="Leaderboard" class="tabcontent"><table class="table-striped"><tbody></tbody></table></div>';
    $(".all_tab_content").empty().append(tableDiv);

    var $tableBody = $('#Leaderboard tbody');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SHEET_ID}/values/Leaderboard?key={API_KEY}',
      success: function(response) {
        // work with the response here...
      },
      complete: function() {
        $indicators.hide(); // hide the loading indicator when the request ends
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note the use of `empty()`, `show()` and `hide()` here.

You also presume you need to change `{SHEET_ID}` and `{API_KEY}` in the URL to their actual values - presuming that's not just redacted data in the question.